# Why is my get method returning null when there are database entries

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

So i am trying to get all Cart instances where the user is currently logged in user
my entities are:
The cart entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="cart_items")
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cart_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="cart_generator", sequenceName = "cart_seq",allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Items.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prdoduct_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Items item;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Client.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Client client;
    
    @Column(name = "item_quantity")
    private int itemQuantity;
    
    @Column(name = "date_of_purchase")
    private LocalDate localDate;
    
    
    @Column(name = "time_of_purchase")
    private LocalTime localTime;
```

the user or client entity

```java
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "client_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="client_generator", sequenceName = "client_seq",allocationSize = 1,initialValue = 1)
    private Integer id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private String roles;
```

the repo

```java
public interface CartRepo extends JpaRepository<Cart,Integer>{
    List<Cart> findByClient(Client client);
}
```

the service

```java
public List <Cart> getCart(Principal principal){
    String clientName=principal.getName();
    Optional<Client> userOp=clientRepo.findByUserName(clientName);

    Client user = userOp.get();

    return cartRepo.findByClient(user);
}
```

and the controller

```java
    @GetMapping("/getCart")
    public List <Cart> getCart(Principal principal){
        return cartService.getCart(principal);
    }
```

I am using Postman for testing and when I log in with a user and try to use this get request my spring boot app crashes and it returns `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`, I have no idea why that is happening from my little knowledge it should be working and its probably something I do not really understand about it so any help is appreciated.

the log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.demo.service.Cartservice.getCart(Cartservice.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.controller.Controller.getCart(Controller.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace

Comment: what is that im realy new if you mean the error log its too big to post you want me to add it to the question field ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the way to do it

Comment: Here you go updated it with the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem has nothing to do with your postman and your database, but this error occurs when you when you try to call a method using a variable that is `null`.

So as stated in the error must be a function `getCart` and you should check if the variable is null before calling any method on it.

```
public List <Cart> getCart(Principal principal){
    if(principal && clientRepo && cartRepo) {
        String clientName=principal.getName();

        Optional<Client> userOp=clientRepo.findByUserName(clientName);
        //check userOp is not null
        Client user = userOp.get();

        return cartRepo.findByClient(user);
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt realy alow me to write it like that if(principal  && cartRepo && clientRepo)

Comment: it says the operator is undefined for these argument types

Comment: i changed it to  if(principal!=null  && cartRepo!=null && clientRepo!=null)

Comment: and its now working properlt can you explain why its working now ?

Comment: sorry this code (principal && cartRepo && clientRepo) using in javascript but in java you should define (principal!=null && cartRepo!=null && clientRepo!=null)

Comment: yea got that thanks for the answer can you tell me why just by checking if its null it works now in reality they were never null cuz I tested them the same way every time